# Como retornar uma coleção de objetos no laravel via ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Criei essa função no meu Controller para retornar uma lista de funcionários na minha requisição ajax, porém não está retornando nada.

```
public function getFuncionarios(Request $request){
    if($info = Funcionario::where('id_empresa', $request->get('empresa'))){
         return response()->json($info);
    }else{
         return 'error';
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu mando retornar a variável direto também não funciona.

```
return $info;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas se eu colocar o `where` para retornar apenas 1 registro funciona.

```
$info = Funcionario::where('id_empresa', $request->get('empresa'))->first()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode ser? Qual seria a forma certa de conseguir o resultado que eu preciso? Essa lista de funcionários seria para alimentar um `<select>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para retornar uma coleção de objetos, pode ser feito também da seguinte forma:

```
public function getFuncionarios(Request $request){

      $funcionarios = Funcionario::whereEmpresa($request->empresa)->get();
      if (!$funcionarios){
           return response()->json(['error' => 'Nenhum funcionário foi encontrado.']);
      }
      return response()->json($funcionarios);
}
```

para retornar um objeto específico:

```
public function getFuncionaio($id){

          $funcionario = Funcionario::find($id);

          return response()->json($funcionario);
    }
```

Comment: muito bom também @MiguelBatista, só usei no caso o where**Id**Empresa pra ficar de acordo com o nome da coluna na minha tabela e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

Dei mole... era só colocar o `get` no final.

```
if($info = Funcionario::where('id_empresa', $request->get('empresa'))->get()){
    return $info;
}
```